# Encountering 'ResourceNotFoundException' when using Amazon Bedrock models

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-bedrock

I'm trying to use the foundational models in Amazon Bedrock to build a simple chatbot using Python. I create Boto3 client and set the model ID, accept and content types as:

```
bedrock = boto3.client(
  service_name='bedrock-runtime', 
  region_name="us-east-1"
)

modelId = 'cohere.command-text-v14'
accept = 'application/json'
contentType = 'application/json'
body = json.dumps({
    "prompt": "Hello World",
    "temperature": 0.75,
    "p": 0.01,
    "k": 0,
})
```

I then try to generate text by using invoke_model:

```
response = bedrock.invoke_model(body=body, modelId=modelId, accept=accept, contentType=contentType)
response_body = json.loads(response.get('body').read())
print(response_body['generations'][0]['text'])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceNotFoundException                 Traceback (most recent call last)

      3 contentType = 'application/json'
      4 
----> 5 response = bedrock.invoke_model(body=body, modelId=modelId, accept=accept, contentType=contentType)
      6 
      7 response_body = json.loads(response.get('body').read())

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    551                 )
    552             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 553             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    554 
    555         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
   1007             )
   1008             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
-> 1009             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
   1010         else:
   1011             return parsed_response

ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the InvokeModel operation: Could not resolve the foundation model from the provided model identifier.
```

I read about this error in the Amazon Bedrock documentation, and it seems to be a problem with the service ARN (unsure what to do about this).
​

Comment: I'm running into the same thing, so I'm watching this question closely

Comment: I got the same error with eu-central-1 region. With us-west-1 all good! Thanks for question. Claude was working with Europe though....

Comment: I am receiving this for both Claude and Llama and a not authorized error when trying Titan. Any additional ideas here? I have access to all these models.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred for me because I hadn't requested access to the model in the AWS Console.

Go to your console, search for bedrock and select model access, then request access to the desired models.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error because I did not specify the region of the Bedrock resource when initiating a new client. The lambda was in `us-east-2`, and so the client was defaulting to looking in that region. I had to specify the region as shown below and then it was working.

Some places online state that you cannot invoke cross-regionally from lambda to Bedrock in different regions but I was able to.

In the lambda:
`const client = new BedrockRuntimeClient({ region: "us-east-1" });`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the base model on Bedrock?

Go to AWS console, search for Bedrock and then you'll see a model access tab. Once there confirm you have access to the relevant model, if not request it. Make sure you are doing this in the same region you are accessing via your client.

Also note that if you happen to do any embedding work, you will need access to a model that supports embeddings specifically - Claude does not.